# Godaddy API fetch all domains automation

Tags: java, api, automation, godaddy-api

Trying to automate a GET request for fetching all domains on my godaddy account, I got it working in postman. However when trying to automate it in IntelliJ with the following code:

```
package godaddy;

import files.Resources;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

public class GodaddyGetTest {


    Properties prop = new Properties();

    @BeforeTest
    public void getData() throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\nerdi\\RestApiCourse\\src\\files\\env.properties");
        prop.load(fis);

        //prop.getProperty("HOST");
    }

    @Test
    public void Test(){

    // write your code here

        //BaseURL or Host
        RestAssured.baseURI = prop.getProperty("GODADDYHOST");

        given().
                header("Authorization", "GODADDYKEY").
                header("Content-Type", "application/json").
                header("Accept", "application/json").
                when().
                get(Resources.godaddyGetData()).
                then().assertThat().statusCode(200).
                and().
                contentType(ContentType.JSON);

    }
}
```

The key is defined in the following way:

```
sso-key Key:SecretKey
```

GODADDYHOST the following way:

```
https://api.godaddy.com
```

Resources.godaddyGetData method looks like this:

```
public static String godaddyGetData(){

        String res = "/v1/domains";
        return res;
    }
}
```

When running this I get the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <401>.


    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:483)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:123)
    at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$statusCode$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:131)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:119)
    at godaddy.GodaddyGetTest.Test(GodaddyGetTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)


===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I fix this?
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see by your stacktrace your test is failing due to it expecting a `200` HTTP code, whereas the actual one you're getting is a `401`.

`401` means that the server responded that your request is unauthorized which most likely means that you're not passing in your authentication key correctly as part of the request's headers.

From this line `header("Authorization", "GODADDYKEY")` I see that you're setting up a header named `Authorization` which you pass in a String equal to `GODADDYKEY`. I assume since it seems that you read this information from a properties file that this is incorrect.

I would therefore advise you to fix your request credentials in the properties file and then retrieve them correctly from your code snippet.

Comment: Thx for this, I noticed that I forgot to actually get the property "GODADDYKEY"
So I changed this line:
header("Authorization", "GODADDYKEY")
To:
header("Authorization", prop.getProperty("GODADDYKEY")).

Comment: Cool, I'm happy that this was resolved for you. Please also take the time to upvote the answer since it was helpful for you.